# Positioning of data points in coord_polar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot angles, the values of which range from -180 to 180 degrees, in `ggplot2` using `coord_polar()` and [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k3il.png).

The data point in the center of the plot corresponds to 160 degrees. Due to the 
 positioning of this data point at the center, the exact angle that the data point represents is not clear from the plot. Is there any way to change the positioning of the data points(representing only angles) in a polar plot?

Here is the code I have used:

```
fl <- read.csv("FlightExperiments_Disc_2018.csv", na.strings = c(""))
fl
flpl<-ggplot()+
geom_point(data = fl, aes(x = factor(Female_ID), y = Angle_callflight_relativesounddirection))+
   coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 1.58, direction = -10)+
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-180, 180, by = 20), limits = c(-180, 180))+
   theme_bw()+ 
   ylab("")+ 
   xlab("")+ 
theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(),
   axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Comment: consider adding your effort to do the same

Comment: @Inder I have explored a lot of options but as of now I am unable to find any that will let me position the data points differently.

Comment: @aswathym could you give the code you use to get this result. This would allow others to better understand the underlying structure of your plot. I believe that playing with a fixed value for y can help. Maybe use the rank of your data points. Something like. 
`df$radius = 1:dim(df)[2]; ggplot(aes(x = angle, y = radius)) +... `
You can also try to define a larger `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(df$radius))) ` supposing your radius is strictly positive, bjt you could reduce the first value to exte'd the distance from the center a'd make the angle more visible.

Comment: @HoboSheep  Thank you so much for your suggestions. I shall try them out. I have added my code in the question.

Comment: @aswathyn I think your code is incomplete. Also try to put it into back quotation marks so it indetifies as code.